# Application of fourier transform in circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis, fourier

[image]I try to solve this question in the following way.
First I take the Fourier transform of the input voltage, and I get $$ 4/j\omega  $$ 
then I find the transfer function.

$$H(\omega) = 4/(4+jw) = v_0/v_S $$
$$ v_0 = (4/(4+jw))v_S  $$
$$v_0 (\omega) = 4/(4+j\omega)(4/j\omega) $$

Then I take the Fourier transform of $$v_0(\omega)$$

where I get $$4(1 - e^{-4t})$$

But the answer is 
$$-2 +4(1 - e^{-4t})$$

Please Help

Thank You very much

Anupam

Answer (score 1):

initial conditions: at t=0-, current = -2 A.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but we are taking Fourier transform of the whole function v_i(t) including the -2 which is -2(dirac(t))